# How to make Bootstrap Dropdown icon and text on the edge?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I do not know why my dropdown centers its child like this:

[image]

This is what I expect

[image]

This is my code from https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown/#dropdowns

```
   <b-dropdown style="width: 200px" text="Period" variant="outline-dark" >
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">An item</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item href="#">Another item</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. if you want the icon at the right side you might want to scroll down a little further to https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown/#split-button-support

Answer (score 0):

Although this is supposed to work like that, you can achieve what you want with the following css:

```
.btn.dropdown-toggle {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
```